# How to edit my htaccess to allow me browse a directory and not blocked by the .php rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Among other conditions I have the following into my htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The problem is that I want to access my `/blog` directory, through `domain.com/blog` but I get a `domain.com/blog/.php` was not found.

How to fix this?

Comment: You could put an .htaccess file into the blog directory that contains `RewriteEngine Off`, this will cancel out the rewrite rules for the blog directory.

Comment: Your rules shouldn't apply for /blog since the blog directory exists.

Answer (score 2):

Your rule shouldn't just `.php` after every non-file, non-directory request as you're doing right now.

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This rule will check for existence of `.php` file first.

Answer (score 1):

add this rule before the other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [L]
```

This will stop the other rules for this directory.

alternative:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog/.*)$
```

Comment: A quick question, how can I allow `blog` and `blog/` ?